# How do I insert a while loop inside of a switch statement?

Tags: c++

My code is almost finished but im not sure how to insert a while loop inside the switch statement so if the user enters a negative number it gives a message, "The value must be positive. Please re-enter: ". Below is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

const double PI = 3.14;
void showMenu();
double area (double, double);
double area (double);
double volume (double, double, double);
double volume (double);

int main()
{
char choice; 
double length, width, height, radius, tot_area, tot_volume;

cout << fixed << setprecision(2);

do
{
showMenu();

cout << "Please select 1-5: " << endl;
cin >> choice;

switch (choice)
{
case '1':
    cout << "Please enter the length of a rectangle: " << endl;
    cin >> length;
    cout << "Please enter the width of a rectangle: " << endl;
    cin >> width;
    tot_area = area(length, width);
    cout << "The area of the rectangle is " << tot_area << endl;
    break;

case '2':
    cout << "Please input the radius of the circle: " << endl;
    cin >> radius;
    tot_area = area(radius);
    cout << "The area of the circle is " << tot_area << endl;
    break;

case '3':
    cout << "Please enter the length of a box: " << endl;
    cin >> length;
    cout << "Please enter the width of a box: " << endl;
    cin >> width;
    cout << "Please enter the height of a box: " << endl;
    cin >> height;
    tot_volume = volume(length, width, height);
    cout << "The volume of the box is " << tot_volume << endl;
    break;

case '4':
    cout << "Please input the radius of a sphere: " << endl;
    cin >> radius;
    tot_volume = volume(radius);
    cout << "The volume of the sphere is " << tot_volume << endl;
    break;

case '5':
    break;

default :
        cout << "That is a invalid operation" << endl;
    break
} 

}

while (choice != '5');
    cout << "Thank you for using my program." << endl;

    return 0;

}


void showMenu()
{
cout << "1. Calculate the area of a rectangle" << endl;
cout << "2. Calculate the area of a circle" << endl;
cout << "3. Calculate the volume of a box" << endl;
cout << "4. Calculate the volume of a sphere" << endl;
cout << "5. Quit" << endl;
}

//For area of a rectangle
double area (double length, double width)
{
return length * width;
}

//For area of a circle
double area (double radius)
{
return PI * pow (radius, 2.0);
}

//For volume of a box
double volume (double length, double width, double height)
{
return length * width * height;
}

//For volume of a sphere
double volume (double radius)
{
return (4.0/3.0) * PI * pow (radius, 3.0);
}
```

Comment: If you want a loop somewhere in there, then put one there. What part of the task are you having trouble with? Have you asked your instructor for help? Stack Overflow is not the place to come to get people to do your homework for you.

Comment: Thanks for your help Rob appreciate it!!

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to insert `while` loop as you are thinking. Use `continue` statement, if the entered input is negative.

Answer (score -2):

You can repeat the same task with the help of do-while:

```
int flag=0;
do {
    cout << "Please enter the length of a rectangle: \n ";
    cin >> length;
    cout << "Please enter the width of a rectangle:\n ";
    cin >> width;

    if (length<0 || width<0)
    {
        flag=1;
        cout << "please enter the positive number";
    }
} while(flag==1);
```

Comment: i tried this one from last 30 minute , but since i am new here so don't know how to write a code , everytimes it's gives code sysntax error at submit stage.

Comment: I've never encountered that problem before, so I assume it's because that example is void of indentation.  Did you also select the code and press CTRL+K to format it?

Comment: Yes i also select ctrl+k and done all the what is suggest but never secceded :(

Comment: Okay, I've fixed it for you.  I recommend you look at that edit and get an idea of how it should look for future reference.